# Separate the searching functionality

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am using `Lucene` in four different web apps to search for items. When I need to change something to how `Lucene` searches or add functionality, I have to build all four apps. I want the searching part separate from the web apps. I am curious as to the best approach. 
I would like to not use web services. We already have a web service app that is in fact one of the apps using lucene search.

All I need to do is return a comma separated list of `itemkeys` matched by the search (or a giant `String`). It should be in Java because everything else is. I am just unsure of the implementation maybe a separate app that returns XML or `JSON` or some `JMS`.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious possibilities are:

1. just go with [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), it has many more things than you probably need, but it's easy to set up, and easy to use, and maybe later you are glad you have those other possibilities it offers...
2. have a look at [this issue in lucene](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5376) that covers creating a search server in plain Lucene. So you can avoid solr.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate your search functionality to a "search server". If you don't want to use solr, you can easyly add this functionality to your code by yourself.

It is unclear to me what you exactly mean with web services but some kind of "remote accessing" technology must be used of course.

You can use a REST interface (e.g. jersey library) where you can define a path like http://serverx.host.domain/search?query=xy for accessing the service.

Or you can use some RPC-mechanism (e.g. http://hessian.caucho.com/) for transparently calling remote java methods. Then you can instantiate the client interface using the url of the service and use the search service as it would be a local interface like

```
String result = searchserver.search("xy");
```

There are endless possibilities of course.

The resulting app can be deployed in a web container like tomcat or you can use an embedded web container like jetty if you want to have a runnable jar.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you another point of view of this problem, since I don't think this problem is related with Lucene itself, but with any common code you could share between the applications.

I would version each application separately, as they seem to have a different lifecycle which causes your problem. Also, I would version the common code in a separate jar file (say Lucene and some other common classes), so you can modify and release a new version every time you have to change it for a particular app.

For instance, suppose that in the beginning all versions of the applications consume the same version of the common code (consider the last part of the names the version):

- `first-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0`
- `second-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0`
- `third-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0`
- `fourth-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0`

Now suppose that I need to modify `lucene-something-1.0` in order to provide a new feature to `third-app-1.0`. I would release `lucene-something-1.1`, and use it for `third-app-1.1` (a new version) leaving the dependencies between modules as this:

- `first-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0` (unchanged)
- `second-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0` (unchanged)
- `third-app-1.1` consumes `lucene-something-1.1`
- `fourth-app-1.0` consumes `lucene-something-1.0` (unchanged)

As you can see, the other applications will remain working as I haven't changed them. You have the new feature for `third-app` and have a "baseline" in the codebase of `lucene-something` which now contains a nice feature for possible future releases of the other apps.

Finally, I would perform all of this with the help of a build tool, such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).